# Error in brachistichrone derivation

Tags: calculus

While attempting an independent derivation of the functional to be minimized in the brachistochrone problem, I derived an equation that prevents the known solution to the problem, specifically
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0\tag{1}$$
where $t\in[0, T]$, $x=x(t)$, and $y=y(x)$. This implies that either the particle is stationary or the curve must be (piecewise) linear. I haven't been able to detect where I went wrong.

For those unfamiliar with the brachistochrone problem, the functional to be minimized is the time taken for a particle constrained to a curve to travel from a point A to a lower point B in the presence of a uniform gravitational field. The curve is assumed to be confined to a plane, and I assume point B is to the right of point A, in the conventional sense.

Throughout, $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$, $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$, and this notation is generalized for higher derivatives in the obvious way. I started by deriving the resultant force on the particle at a given point on a somewhat arbitrary curve.  $$F(x)=m(\vec{g}^T\vec{e})\vec{e}\tag{2}$$
where $\vec{g}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-g\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{e}=\frac{\tau(x)}{\lVert\tau(x)\rVert}$ for $\tau(x)=\begin{bmatrix}1&y'(x)\end{bmatrix}$, a unit vector tangent to the curve. This should yield the component of the gravitational force tangent to the curve, which I find to be $$F(x)=-\frac{mgy'}{1+(y')^2}\begin{bmatrix}1&y'\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}$$

Next, I set up equations describing Newton's 2nd:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{gy'}{1+y'^2}\tag{4}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-\frac{gy'^2}{1+y'^2}\tag{5}$$

As I've defined $y$ to only implicitly depend on $t$, I rewrite the LHS of $(5)$ through the chain rule, yielding the equations:
$$\ddot{x}=-\frac{gy'}{1+y'^2}\tag{4*}$$
$$\dot{x}^2y''+\ddot{x}y'=-\frac{gy'^2}{1+y'^2}\tag{5*}$$
which should hold for all $t$. The erroneous equation emerges from these two equations. By multiplying $(4^*)$ by $-y'$ and taking the linear combination of this with  $(5^*)$, equation $(1)$ is obtained. What gives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All right, I tracked down my issue. The force is not generally constrained to the tangent of the curve. Rather, this is only the case when the slope is constant. The degenerate case of a stationary particle also satisfies this constraint. This explains equation $(1)$.

Looks like this ended up being more of a physics than a math question.